# how to find consecutive 1 from last column of data frame and count how many time

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

there are 5 column in 1st data frame . by using this find consecutive 1 from last D_4 to D_1, if find 0 in between then break and till that how many ones and that will be output

[image: 1st input data frame]

[image: 2nd input data frame]

[image: output data frame]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate each row as string from D_4 to D_1, split strings once at first '0' then get the length of the first part:

```py
df['lco'] = (df.iloc[:, :0:-1].astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1)
                              .str.split('0', n=1).str[0].str.len())
print(df)

# Output
  Code  D_1  D_2  D_3  D_4  lco
0    A    0    1    0    1    1
1    B    1    1    0    1    1
2    C    0    0    1    1    2
3    D    1    1    1    1    4
4    E    0    0    0    1    1
5    F    0    0    0    0    0
6    G    1    1    1    0    0
7    H    1    0    1    1    2
```

Comment: interesting use of `split`, this only works with single digits numbers though

Comment: Yes of course. `melt` is probably the right answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can `melt`, use a reverse `cummin` per group to get rid of the trailing 1s, then count the 1s:

```py
df.merge(df.melt('Code', value_name='num')
           .groupby('Code')['num']
           .apply(lambda s: s[::-1].cummin().sum()),
         on='Code'
         )
```

or, in place, with `stack`:

```py
df['num'] = (df
   .iloc[:,1:].stack()
   .groupby(level=0)
   .apply(lambda s: s[::-1].cummin().sum())
)
```

output:

```
  Code  D_1  D_2  D_3  D_4  num
0    A    0    1    0    1    1
1    B    1    1    0    1    1
2    C    0    0    1    1    2
3    D    1    1    1    1    4
4    E    0    0    0    1    1
5    F    0    0    0    0    0
6    G    1    1    1    0    0
7    H    1    0    1    1    2
```